# "Please fill out this field" instead of custom errors message | Symfony 5

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, bootstrap-5

Hello I have a Symfony 5 form with constraints for my fields, my constraint for Length works perfectly, but NotBlank not correctly. I have a "type" and "label" field, I'm testing the form and the constraints with "type", if I validate my form with "type" empty, it displays the default browser message "Please fill out this field" whereas I'd like to have my custom message that I've defined in my entity for the "NotBlank" constraint.

I think the problem is caused by the "required => true" because if I change it to "false" and add an "empty_data => '' " it works and I can see my custom message but not completely because in my modification form, if I empty the "type" field and validate, it will bug with this message: Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "type".

I'm using Symfony 5, Bootstrap 5, here's my entity, my twig form and my FormType.php

Entity

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 2,
     *      max = 50,
     *      minMessage = "Le type doit faire au minimum {{ limit }} caractères",
     *      maxMessage = "Le type doit faire au maximum {{ limit }} caractères"
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *      message = "Le type est un champ obligatoire"
     * )
     */
    private $type;
```

Twig form

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="container-card-global mb-5">
        <div class="form-field">
            {{form_label(form.type)}}
            {{form_errors(form.type)}}
            {{form_widget(form.type)}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            {{form_label(form.description)}}
            {{form_widget(form.description)}}
            {{form_errors(form.description)}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            {{form_label(form.statut)}}
            {{form_widget(form.statut)}}
        </div>


        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-save-global">{{ button_label|default('Valider') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

FormType.php

```
$builder
            ->add('type', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Type',
            ])
```

Ty for help !

I've looked at some forums, I've tried using "novalidate" but it comes back the same, the same error message, I'd really like to keep "required => true" and manage to get my custom message "this field cannot be blank".

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing server side error and front side error.
When you write `required => true` it will apply the html attribute `required` to your input element. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

This is why you see default brower error. You can inspect your input html tag with F12 and remove the required if you want to try.

Then. If you manage to submit the form (sending data to server). Symfony will apply its own constraint (your assert).

This is why your form show your error properly since you used this function on each entry of your form `form_errors`.

But in that case, the error you see are returned from the server. They are not browser error.

Anyway, keeping `required => true` is good for UX (User experience). And for a complete UX, having only "dynamic" error showing is a good thing. It prevent user to be forced to submit before knowing he made mistake.

BUT Symfony constraint are also here to PROTECT what someone can submit so you never get incomplete data registered. You can see it as the "wall of china". The last thing that project your project data.

Comment: D'accord merci  @ThomasL j'ai compris ta réponse, donc moi je veux utiliser les server side error plutot que celle du navigateur, donc si j'ai bien compris je vais devoir notifier `required => false`.

Sauf que quand je fais ça, j'ai toujours cette erreur qui apparait _Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "type"._ alors que mon assert est bien présente comme ceci : `->add('type', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Type',
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['message' => 'non'])],
            ])`

Comment: J'ai bien mis également cette ligne la au début de mon fichier `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;`

Comment: Tu peux me montrer ton setter dans l'entité ? A mon avis tu l'as typé string et non ?string

Comment: Effectivement c'était bien ca l'erreur, par défaut tout mes champs sont en string et non ?string dans le setter de l'entité , merci beaucoup de ton aide !

Comment: @MeyoGIT je t'en prie avec plaisir !

Answer (score 0):

For form classes you need to add the constraint like this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes

Comment: No it's not working @iruoy , if i set 'required => true' and add my constraint as it is said it will still display the default browser message "Please fill out this field" instead of my custom message `->add('type', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Type',
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['message' => 'non'])],
            ])` and if i set 'required => false' i will have this error _Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "type"._

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** :
Il faut aller dans le setter du champ de l'entité et ajouter un ***?*** juste avant le string, on passe simplement de ça :

```
public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }
```

à ca :

```
public function setType(?string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }
```